# Best way to handle multiple authorization schemes between ASP NET Core back-end and React.js front-end

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, hmac

We're in the initial phase of a project and we're trying to determine the best possible authorization scheme(s) between our back-end services and a front-end application which is going to be developed in React.js

The main thing here is that we will basically have two types of functionalities: **allowed for anonymous user** and **allowed only for authenticated** users. Our goal is to postpone the sign-up process until the customer decides that he really needs to do that. Until then, he will be able to browse all kind of other stuff on the website.

And the other important aspect is that we want to make our services accessible only through the React.js application which is developed by us.

[image]

For that purpose, we've been thinking about [HMAC Authentication for the Web Api service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/rest-api-authentication-hmac). So, by default we can build a trust between our back-end and a specific front-end/client application. But, I have two questions here:

1. How do I store the sensitive key information on the client?
2. When a user decides to sign-up isn't this gonna be a different authorization flow (oAuth) so wouldn't it get messed up with the HMAC?

In general, I am looking for suggestions here. I hope I explained the scenario well enough.

Comment: We save sensitive info on the client only if the info is encrypted & can be expired or if the client's code cannot be reverse-engineered. But I don't think it's easy to prevent reverse-engineering so you can make it hard for many users (to break your system) but cannot completely protect it from being broken by some experts. Basically for the purpose of limiting as much as possible, you can accept that at a degree. Unless you own the user's device (manufactured by you), it's really hard to completely ensure the identity of your client app which is basically readable by anyone.

Comment: for the second point, multiple authentication handlers can all be run, each authentication handler can add up a set of claims which are combined to the final claims set (to build the principal). So I don't see any conflict here. You can reject at any step, if all succeeded, you have the combined claims set. The authorization next will have necessary data to authorize the request.

Comment: @KingKing Okay, I understand that there's kind of a risk to implement HMAC with a SPA client. One side question - what if my client application was ASP.NET MVC app instead of React.js?

Comment: if you mean about securing your client app's identity, I see no much difference. I don't know much about react.js, but it looks like can be used for mobile app programming, it then may be a bit more secure (because users cannot easily see the source code like with web apps run via a browser). But even when you use native apps (for mobile & Windows ...), there is always a chance the code (logic) and data can be exploited by ***experts***. It can defend against most of users but not completely (as I said).